# Oracle/PLSQL. Select only best match between two tables

Tags: oracle, match

I have two tables:

```
Vehicles 
make    model         modification    
Audi     A 5         A 5 2010 Sportsback 2.8      
Audi     A 5         A 5 2012 Quattro L     
Audi     A 5         A 5 Cabriolet
```

and

```
matchingModel 
make    model      modContain    modEnd    finalModel    
Audi     A 5       Sportback              A5 Sportback
Audi     A 5                       L        A5 L
Audi     A 5                                A5
```

My task is to get only best fitting finalModel by finding matches (can be seen in select below).
First i tried to join tables

```
(SELECT 
matchingModel.finalModel
  FROM vehicles
    LEFT OUTER JOIN matchingModel ON 
matchingModel.TEXT1 = vehicles.make

    AND vehicles.model = nvl(matchingModel.model,vehicles.model)
    AND vehicles.modification LIKE decode(matchingModel.modContain, NULL, vehicles.modification, '%'||matchingModel.modContain||'%')
    AND vehicles.modification LIKE decode(matchingModel.modEnd, NULL, vehicles.modification, '%'||' '||matchingModel.modEnd)
)
AS bestMatch
```

but that did not work, because as Sportsback was found as sportsback, later its overwritten as a simple A5 because that matches too.

So next i made this happen simply by "nvling" all possible options: nvl(nvl(nvl(select where make, model fits and modContains is in the middle of Modification and option cell is empty), (select where make, model fits and modEnd is like ending of Modification and modEnd is not empty), (select where make and model fits AND so on)) AS Bestmatch
This works, but it is very slow (and both tables have more that 500k records).

This is just a part of very huge select, so its difficult to rewrite this normal way. 
Anyway, the question is, are there any best practices how to get best match, only once, fast, in oracle? The problems i have run into, is performance, or values fits twice, or "where" clause does not work, because i can not know if modContain or modEnd is empty or not.

Thank You in advance.
Sorry for English.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite there yet but I worked out an example you can continue to work out for yourself: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bce8/9)

```
select * from (
(select 
  case when v.modification like '%'||m.modContain||'%' then 2
       when m.modcontain is null                       then 1
                                                       else 0 end m1,
       case when v.modification like '%'||m.modend     then 2
            when m.modend is null                      then 1
                                                       else 0 end m2
 , m.make mmake, m.model mmodel, modcontain, modend, finalmodel
 , v.make vmake, v.model vmodel, modification
from vehicles v, matchingmodel m
where
     v.make  = m.make
 and soundex(v.model) = soundex(m.model) ) ) x
order by m1+m2 desc
```

So the sub-query adds together the matches and the highest match should be your best match. I also used soundex which may also help you because `Sportback` and `Sportsback` is not quite the same and that helped me to make `A5` and `A 5` make the same. Also to make it fast you will have to work a lot with assigning good indicies and watching the explain plan, especially if you have 500k records. That is not an easier undertaking.

To the idea about writing a procedure (which is a good idea) untested it might look like this:

```
create or replace function vehicle_matching(i_vehicles vehicles%rowtype,
                                            i_matchingmodel matchingmodel%rowtype)
return number
is
   l_return number;
begin
   if   i_vehicles.modification like '%'||i_matchingmodel.modContain||'%' then 
      l_return := 3;
   elsif soundex(i_vehicles.modification) like '%'||soundex(i_matchingmodel.modContain)||'%' then
      l_return := 2;
...

   if i_vehicles.modification like '%'||i_matchingmodel.modend then
      l_return := l_return + 1; -- there is no i++ in PL/SQL
   elsif 
...

   return l_return;
end vehicle_matching;
```

Also I was thinking if it is more efficient to work with `INSTR` and `SUBSTR` than with the `%` but I actually do not really think this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

you may consider something like this:

write a query to return 1 on any partial match
then write another query to return another 1 on another partial match - etc.

repeat this for all possible columns that count towards your 'similarity'

in the end, you will find the row with the highest sum (or count) of 1's and that will be the closest match.

Comment: Thank You for reply. I considered this, but i do not know how to use variables. Tried different ways:
    declare
     i number;
     i := 0
    begin
     case 
      when 
      exists(my selection)
      then i++
      elseif and so on
    end;
This does not work at all. The very beginning, declaration does not work. Maybe the problem is that i use sqldbx. I do not have any other interface, meaning i do not have access to java, php or any other programming language to make it easier.
Also, I'm a complete beginner at plsql and sql as such.